# make:No rule to make target `/usr/local/lib/libsuperlu.so'

Tags: makefile, armadillo

I tried type "make" to generate the run-time armadillo library while installing armadillo-8.500.0, it always show

```
***No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/libsuperlu.so', 
needed by 'libarmadillo.so.8.500.0'.Stop.
***[CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/all] Error 2
make:***[all]Error 2
```

I tried several solution applied on Internet, but all of them didn't work for my problem. Some says libsuperlu.so didn't exist in /usr/local/lib, but it already shows

```
--Looking for SuperLU version 5 
--Found SuperLU:/usr/local/lib/libsuperlu.so
--SuperLU_FOUND=YES
--SuperLU_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include
```

after running "cmake".

I tried

```
$stat /usr/local/lib/libsuperlu.so
```

it shows

```
File:'/usr/local/lib/libsuperlu.so'->'libsuperlu.so.5'
```

How to solve the problem?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the existing link "libsuperlu.so" is broken.
After checking the property of "libsuperlu.so", found out it's broken. Then I delete the old 'so' file, relink it. It worked.